# jQuery and multi-select

Tags: jquery, multi-select

On my page I have to select option values loaded by a $.post function.  I have a button to "move" data from one select to the other. The example works in a new page but not in my page not. The elements selected do not move to the other select after the click.

The question is there is another way to do it or how can I correct my page for making it work?

Example code:

```
<div style="float:left; border:1px solid red;">
    <div style="background-color:red; color:white;" align="center">INFORMATIVE</div>
    <div id="prop_info" style="float:left;">
        <div style="border:1px solid red;">PROPOSTI</div>
        <div style="float:left"><select multiple id="sel_info_pro" name="sel_info_pro" class="sel"><option value="b">a</option><option>b</option></select></div>
        <div style="float:left;"><a href="#" id="add_info"> >> </a><br><a href="#" id="remove_info"> << </a></div>
    </div>  
    <div id="conf_info" style="float:left;">
        <div style="border:1px solid red;">CONFIGURATI</div>
        <select multiple id="sel_info_conf" name="sel_info_conf" class="sel"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add_info').click(function() {
        return !$('#sel_info_pro option:selected').remove().appendTo('#sel_info_conf');
    });
    $('#remove_info').click(function() {
        return !$('#sel_info_conf option:selected').remove().appendTo('#sel_info_pro');
    });
});
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work in your page?

Comment: Thanks for answering, clicking on the "button" the value does not move in the other select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my working solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#add_info').click(function() {
    var foop = []; 
    $('#sel_info_pro option:selected').each(function(z, selected){ 
        foop[z] = $(selected).val(); 
        return !$('#sel_info_pro option:selected').val(foop[z]).remove().appendTo('#sel_info_conf'); 
    });
}); 
$('#remove_info').click(function() { 
    var foo = []; 
    $('#sel_info_conf option:selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
        foo[i] = $(selected).val(); 
        return !$('#sel_info_conf option:selected').val(foo[i]).remove().appendTo('#sel_info_pro'); 
    });
});
```

});

thanks everybody for help!

Answer (score 1):

A bit guidance that might help. If you did the following:

```
alert($('#sel_info_pro option:selected').length);
```

Then you would get 0, regardless of how many you had selected

The selected options are actually stored against the `val()` on the jQuery object:

```
alert($('#sel_info_pro option').val().length); //gives you the count of options selected
alert($('#sel_info_pro option').val()[0]); //gives you the value of the first option selected
```

So, the approach above will not work. You may have to iterate through the array, comparing them to each item in the list to move them over.

This link may also help: http://marcgrabanski.com/articles/jquery-select-list-values

Comment: Thanks for your answer James Wiseman I get strange answer from alerts: the first one work right gives me the number of elements selected,the second value's number of chararacters the third return only the first character